# Using wrong namespace in the Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller: "/app/controllers/analyst/test_orders_controller.rb".

In this file I have:

```
class Analyst::TestOrdersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end
end
```

But I have an error:

```
uninitialized constant Analyst::TestOrdersController::Order
```

But I don't want to use `Analyst::TestOrdersController::Order.new`, I just want to use `Order.new`. It is strange. What is the problem?

Comment: Is your `Order` class accessible from `rails console`?

Comment: Try using `@order = ::Order.new`

Comment: @Marek_Lipka, Yea, of course. I have about 30 controllers which use this class.

Comment: @dax, I know this solution, but I think it is just a hack. And what is the matter of this strange behavior?

Comment: Why is it just a hack?  It takes you out of the current scope which is exactly what you want

Comment: using `::Order.new` actually solves your problem?

Comment: Does anyone know why this is happening here specifically?

Comment: Yes, the models are loaded lazily so Order is assumed to be defined locally inside Analyst module, calling ::Order tells the app to look for the definition in the Rails paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `::Order.new`
The interpreter is looking for the definition of Order under the `Analyst` module namespace, this happens because the application models are loaded lazily so the file models/order.rb has not been read yet. Adding the general namespace tells it search for the definition in the Rails paths.

The way to confirm this is to add some random function call in the Order model body and see that it's not executed unless you call ::Order explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
module  Analyst
  class TestOrdersController < ApplicationController
    def new
      @order = Order.new
    end
  end
end
```

I think it has to do with module nesting:
https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup